# Seeding Words to LDA model in R/Python

Tags: python, r, lda, seeding, text-analysis

I want to do LDA topic analysis over a huge corpus. I have tried that in R and Python. Now I'd like to seed special words into the model. That means that I have some prior probability for some words associated with topics and I want seed these to the model. As I searched only, function LDA() in R and gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel() in python both have such paremters.

But I hardly saw any example codes using that thus I have no ideas about how to input my priors into the model. Can anyone provide some help? Thanks.

Comment: Working on LDA myself. Would like to know the answer to this. On a side note is there a email/chat feature here as I would like to know more about what you plan on doing once you have the LDA topics.